# Two horizontal lines above and under chapter-entry

Tags: sectioning, chapters, rules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Title between lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86013/title-between-lines)

Can anybody please tell me how to get horizontal lines above and under the `\chapter{MyChapter}`? Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) does this help: [title-between-lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86013/title-between-lines)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Not a proper answer, but take a look at the `titlesec` package, there is an example on page 22 of [the manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/titlesec).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\huge}
  {\filleft\Large\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}
  {3ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1.5ex}\filright}
  [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Test Unnumbered Chapter}
\chapter{Test Numbered Chapter}

\end{document}
```

An image of the unnumbered chapter:

[image]

and an image of the numbered chapter:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It looks amazing. *thumbs up* and have a nice day. =)

Comment: How can I solve this without using the titlesec-package (because of using scrbook-class)?

Comment: @Dave Please, feel free to open a fresh new question.

Comment: Well fine, how to manage the same for the `list of contents` and `list of tables`? Moreover, how to apply the above mentioned stuffs while writing a thesis using `report class` and including chapters.