# \titleformat (in titlesec) doesn't show any horizontal line for chapter

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec, rules

I have been trying to get a simple thing working with `titlesec`: getting a horizontal line under each chapter. There are many tutorials, documents and questions on [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) that explain how this can be done. But ... each one of those answers have given me absolutely nothing. These are the solutions I have tried:

1. [Add a rule after chapter title using titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69330/add-a-rule-after-chapter-title-using-titlesec)
2. [Two horizontal lines above and under chapter-entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93789/two-horizontal-lines-above-and-under-chapter-entry)
3. [Title between lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86013/title-between-lines)

But in each case, the compiled pdf shows exactly what it was showing without any use of `\titleformat`. My current preamble uses `titlesec` as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
% Below "\section" can be replaced with "\subsection" and "\subsubsection"
% in order to customize the corresponding headings. "bch" - Bitstream
% Charter, "b" - bold.
\titleformat{\section}[hang]
{\usefont{T1}{bch}{b}{n}\selectfont}
{}    % label
{0em} % horizontal separation between label and title body
{\hspace{-0.4pt}\Large \thesection\hspace{0.6em}} % before-code
[] % after-code

\titleformat
{\chapter}                       % command
[display]                        % shape
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}      % format
{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter} % label
{20pt}                           % sep
{\Huge}[\vspace{2ex}\titlerule]  % before-code
```

This is just one of at least a dozen variations I have tried (including the example at the end of the [titlesec documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/titlesec/titlesec.pdf), including the `{name=\chapter,numberless}` method explained in section 3.8, but all I have to show for it is this screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, there is no horizontal line anywhere over, under or near the chapter "Abstract". The document is nearly empty right now. After the preamble ends, all I have is

```
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter*{Abstract}
Lorem Ipsum etc. etc.
\end{document}
```

I hope I was able to provide an MWE. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here so that even the most basic example is producing no result.

Comment: I get a rule when I compile your code `titlesec 2011/12/15 v2.10.0`

Answer (score 2):

You have defined the format for numbered chapters and using an un-numbered chapter for `Abstract`. Defining the format for un-numbered chapters too is needed in this case to get a rule.

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
% Below "\section" can be replaced with "\subsection" and "\subsubsection"
% in order to customize the corresponding headings. "bch" - Bitstream
% Charter, "b" - bold.
\titleformat{\section}[hang]
{\usefont{T1}{bch}{b}{n}\selectfont}
{}    % label
{0em} % horizontal separation between label and title body
{\hspace{-0.4pt}\Large \thesection\hspace{0.6em}} % before-code
[] % after-code

\titleformat
{\chapter}                       % command
[display]                        % shape
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}      % format
{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter} % label
{20pt}                           % sep
{\Huge}[\vspace{2ex}\titlerule]  % before-code

\titleformat
{name=\chapter,numberless}                       % command
[display]                        % shape
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}      % format
{} % label
{0pt}                           % sep
{\Huge}[\vspace{2ex}\titlerule]  % before-code    %% adjust 2ex here as you want.

\begin{document}
%\maketitle
\chapter*{Abstract}
Lorem Ipsum etc. etc.
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have not adjusted the spacing. Please do so using `\titlespacing*`  The default is

```
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
```

Please do it also for un-numbered chapters using

```
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter,numberless} {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
```

Comment: I had tried this option too, as mentioned in the question, but it didn't give me the horizontal rule. I did, however, find out what was causing the behavior I witnessed: : *after* defining `titleformat`, I was importing another package `\usepackage{sectsty}`. Once I commented out that line, everything started working as expected.

Comment: @ChthonicProject Don't use both those packages but only one of them.

Comment: that's what I ended up doing. Initially, I didn't see any conflict or incompatibility mentioned in the documentation of `sectsty` (maybe it is there, but I missed it somehow), so I had included both. Now, I am only using `titlesec`.